# Java - pass in array values

Tags: java

Is it possible to pass in array values?

```
test ([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

---

```
public void test(int[] foo) {
    for (int i : foo) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Your outputs don't make sense; those aren't ints.

Comment: @SLaks I apologize for the typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - you just need to create a new array in the calling code:

```
test(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Or you could change your method declaration like this to use a [varargs parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
public void test(int... foo)
```

and then call it with:

```
test(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an idea why my questions received 4 downvotes? Can you recommend how I can improve my questions for the future?

Comment: @Growler: I suspect the downvoters thought you should have done more research first. Also you've clearly changed the question (even since I answered it) - given SLaks' comment, it's entirely possible that three of the downvotes were due to it not making sense in its original form.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to create an array:

```
new int[] { a, b, c, d }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use this syntax:

```
test(new Object[]{bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4});
```

Be sure to replace `Object` with the correct data type

Comment: @JonSkeet, I was providing the general syntax, since the OP clearly was not aware of it. No need to down vote my answer.

Comment: You provided an answer which wouldn't work, without giving any explanation. I think it's entirely reasonable that anyone reading your answer would have *expected* it to work with no further changes. There's therefore every reason to downvote your answer, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I suppose you would also have downvoted me if my method call didn't end in a semi-colon, seeing as how that would not "work with no further changes."

Comment: No - that would have been incomplete as a statement, but still a valid method call. That's reasonable, as there's no claim that this is a complete program, and thus no expectation that it would compile *on its own*. I think there *is* a reasonable expectation that it would compile *as part of a slightly bigger program* though (including the method declaration as given by the OP).

Comment: @JonSkeet, Yes, but I clearly specified my answer as being the correct "syntax". The other day I asked a question and someone wrote a small class to solve my problem. The class they wrote had at least 4 errors, but I was able to fix them, so I upvoted them and chose their answer. You are free to do as you wish with your votes, but my  opinion is that this particular case was unreasonable. Regardless, I have edited my answer to include "Be sure to replace Object with the correct data type"

Comment: I don't know why you didn't fix it to just use the right type. Why make it more obscure than it needed to be? (I can't undo my downvote now without another edit to the post. I would only undo the downvote in its current state though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, because I was providing a general syntax. It makes perfect sense if you read my answer as an answer to his question. "Is it possible to pass in array values?"

Comment: And if that's *all* he'd asked, that would be fine. But when a specific example is given, and you give an answer which *appears* to be trying to answer that specific example (it calls a `test` method and uses the `bar1`, `bar2` etc variables which were originally in the question) then deliberately making that example fail seems unhelpful to me. If you'd *just* written the array creation part, I wouldn't have downvoted - although I still think that giving an example meeting the specified need is *more* helful.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I can see your point. I'll consider this in the future.

Answer (score -1):

you can not put String place of Integer ..
you can use this code.

```
class Test
{
    public void test1(String[] foo) 
   {
        for (String i : foo) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        String x[] ={"b1","b2","b3","b4"};

        Test t1 =  new Test();

        t1.test1 (x);

    }

}
```

Comment: You most certainly can pass an `int` into `System.out.println()`. See here: http://ideone.com/1hcRta

Comment: but you can not pass string to int ... either bar1 bar2 should be variable ... or you can not pass them to int .. in java.. you can do it in php..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Can you give me an example?